# Android gravity start/end has no effect on Arabic text?

Tags: android, arabic, right-to-left

Google has introduced a couple of new flags for gravity of views: specifically, `start` and `end`. I am trying to use these in my application, but they don't seem to have the desired effect in Arabic.

2 TextViews with gravity `start`

What I expect:

```
English Locale
------------------
|day             |

Arabic Locale
------------------
|             يوم|
```

What I get

```
------------------
|Day             |

------------------
|يوم             |
```

Why is this? Isn't this exactly what `start` and `end` were supposed to fix?

My project targets SDK 14, which is when `start` and `end` were introduced.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Please provide your xml. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file?

Comment: I thought of that, but that is only supported in API level 17 and higher as far as I can tell.

Comment: I changed my eclipse project target to API 17, although my android:sdkTarget is 14. That works for now, but I don't know if this will cause problems. I will have to do some more testing and find out.